# Cause AngularJS Route using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to have my website route to another page. The routing is successful when clicking on an a tag to /projects, but I am trying to do animations before the route occurs.

I have the a tag initiating a function which does a series of animations. After the animations I try to go to /projects using:

`window.location.href = 'projects';`

which does not work.

I am curious if there is a way to have jQuery route me to /projects from /.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `$state` service.

Pass `$state` service in controller and use `$state.go("projects")`.

Comment: Can you share a working demo to help us understand and solve your issue.You can share demo on jsfiddle